# How many positive integers less than or equal to $500$ have exactly $3$ positive divisors?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> How many positive integers less than or equal to $500$ have exactly $3$ positive divisors?

My approach was to use the following inequality $N \leqslant 500$, where $N$ is the number of positive integers that have exactly $3$ positive divisors. Prime factorizing $500$ one would get that $500 = 2^2 \cdot 5^3$. Wouldn't this imply that $N$ would have to be of the form $N = 2^a \cdot 5^b$ and from the given condition we would get that $(a+1)(b+1) = 3$? However I couldn't get this any further. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: 8, they are 4, 9, 25, 49, 121, 169, 289, 361. If you ignore 1 as a divisor, then there are 149, they are here https://pastebin.com/hKc53q1T

Answer (score 4):

For $n$ to have exactly $3$ positive divisors, $1$ must be a factor, $n$ must be a factor and also we need another factor say $p$.

We need $\frac{n}{p}=p$ and $p$ is a prime. Prime is needed or additional divisors exists.

Hence $n$ must be a prime square.

Since $\sqrt{500}\approx 22.3$, the numbers are $2^2, 3^2, 5^2, 7^2, 11^2, 13^2, 17^2, 19^2$.

Answer (score 1):

A number has exactly 3 positive divisors iff it is of the form $p^2$ where $p$ is prime. The following are $<500$: 4, 9, 25, 49, 121, 169, 289, 361 (8 numbers).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to prime factorize $500$. The number of divisors of an integer $n$ is given by $$\prod_{i=1}^k (e_i+1)$$ where $n = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{e_i}$ (i.e. the prime factorization). It is then easy to see that the only way $n$ would have exactly $3$ positive divisors is if $n = p^2$ with $p$ prime.

Then the problem reduces to finding the number of $n = p^2 \le 500 \to p \le \sqrt{500} \approx 22.4$. There are $8$ primes less than or equal to $22$: $ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19$. Therefore, the answer is $8$.

Comment: Hmm I don't see how $p^2$ would imply the $3$ positive factors? What's the intuition there?

Comment: Well, the only factors of $p^2$ would be $1, p, p^2$ (assuming that $p$ is prime).

Comment: Or another way to think about it is that there can only be one factor (other than $1$ and $n$). But if $k$ is a factor, then $n/k$ must also be a factor. Since you need exactly $3$ factors, $k = n/k \to n = k^2$